# Setting RUSTUP_HOME and CARGO_HOME before running rustup installation does not work in Windows

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rustup

Defining RUSTUP_HOME and/or CARGO_HOME environment variables to override default installation directory for .cargo and .rustup does not work (in Windows at least).

**Steps to reproduce:**

- Define RUSTUP_HOME as an environment variable
- Define CARGO_HOME as an environment variable
- Double click on rustup-init.exe to begin the installation

**Result:**

.rustup and .cargo will be installed at the default directory which is %USERPROFILE%.

Comment: Did you really go into "System Properties" to edit the user/system env vars, to define those? Because otherwise the "double click .exe" doesn't make sense

Comment: Additionally, if this is an actual bug, then it feels like something that should be submitted to the [rustup issue tracker](https://github.com/rust-lang/rustup/issues). There's also the related [issue #618](https://github.com/rust-lang/rustup/issues/618)

Comment: Yes, I added both variables in "System Properties" and tried user and system as well. Both didn't work for me. Maybe this is just an issue on my PC specifically because the solution to run it from the terminal seems strange. It's like the environment variables only get loaded when you open the terminal window first?

Answer (score 0):

After defining RUSTUP_HOME and CARGO_HOME environment variables, run rustup-init.exe from the terminal like `.\Downloads\rustup-init.exe` instead of double clicking the .exe file.